How to get back cloned repos in Github Desktop
I have nearly 40 cloned repositorises from github.com in my github-desktop app. Today for some reason, I opened /snap folder and executed github-desktop binary directly ...it opened but shown "Lets Get Started" page...means my repositorises are no longer visible...Now when I open Github-Desktop using "Show Applications" icon (Ubuntu 22.04) it is not showing my repositorises...How to get back the repositorises
I tried restarting both app and then system...cant get back my repos cloned from github

In my GitHub Desktop interface there's a File menu with an option to Add Local Repository.  I imagine yours would have something similar, no?  Even without speculating on why the application "forgot" about them, they can just be re-added back can't they?

I opened my system after 7 months. I forgot those repo names also...Yes I can add individually by going to the root folder and checking each folder name...but Im sure github desktop has config files where it stores repos information...that will be decent and proper way, right? BTW I have two versions of Github Desktop. 2.0.4 and 2.9.2. In an attempt to uninstall old one I messed u new one..I forgot how I installed the old one, so was digging the /snap folder...old one has all the repos and working fine btw :)

Do you actually know where you keep Git repositories on your computer? If so, are the Git repositories still in that directory? If not, maybe search your entire hard-disk for ".gitignore" and see what files you find.

Yes I know ...they are in ~/code directory...for examle...python repos are in ~/code/python...java repos are in ~/code/java
